# SwiftData entity not found crash in multi-configuration ModelContainer setup

Tags: swift, cloudkit, swift-data

In my `ModelContainer` I separated some models into two configurations because I want to have some of the model data synced via CloudKit and the other be locally saved only. This I the code I used to setup the ModelContainer

```swift
let cloudKitEntities: [any PersistentModel.Type] = [
    A.self, B.self, C.self
]
let localEntities: [any PersistentModel.Type] = [
   X.self, Y.self, Z.self
]
        
let cloudKitSchema = Schema(cloudKitEntities)
let localSchema = Schema(localEntities)
let combinedSchema = Schema(cloudKitEntities + localEntities)
        
let cloudKitConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: cloudKitSchema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: isStoredInMemoryOnly)
let localConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: localSchema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: isStoredInMemoryOnly)

return try ModelContainer(for: combinedSchema, configurations: [cloudKitConfiguration, localConfiguration])
```

I created a ModelActor which is in charge of importing and persisting some data on a separate context.

```swift
actor Importer: ModelActor {
    
let modelContainer: ModelContainer
let modelExecutor: ModelExecutor
    
init(modelContainer: ModelContainer) {
    self.modelContainer = modelContainer
    let context = ModelContext(modelContainer)
    context.autosaveEnabled = false
    modelExecutor = DefaultSerialModelExecutor(modelContext: context)
}
    
func `import`(from data: APIExport) async throws {
    // prepare import by deleting all persisted `X` models to start on a clean state
    try modelContext.delete(model: X.self)
}
```

`import` crashes with
"*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSFetchRequest could not locate an NSEntityDescription for entity name 'X''"

The injected modelContainer is exactly the container as described in the code above.
By debugging and printing the modelContainer I can also see that there is in fact an entity with name: X available

Is there anything wrong with my setup?

Comment: You're not the only one. I have seen a few people mention this problem now and I have submitted a Feedback Report on it. (FB13504577)

Comment: Thanks for linking this. Let’s see whether this has been fixed in the new Xcode release